# Delete a line starting with particular String in all 3000 files

Tags: perl, awk, sed, grep, notepad

I want to delete a particular line in each of 3000 text files.

I have tried using Notepad Plus but it creates a blank line for each matching line.

#### Sample File Content:

```
SAMPLE TXT FILE
---------------------
phone number
address
IAM A DEFAULT
city
state
pincode
----------------
```

Here `IAM A DEFAULT` is present in all 3000 files and it is present only once

Comment: Hi perl, It is a single line with same string in all files

Comment: Perl, The line to be dropped is always the same string. Eg, I have to delete all the line that contain string "iam new to perl"  in all 3000 files

Comment: Then: `perl -n -i.before -e 'print unless /iam new to perl/;' *.txt`. This will print all lines NOT containing "iam new to perl", edit the files in-place (`-i`) and save the old files as `*.before` (`-i.before`).

Comment: Do you have GNU `sed` available?  If so, then you can test with `sed -i.bak -e '/^IAM A DEFAULT/d' somefiles.txt` and drop the `.bak` when you're satisfied it works and supply the whole file name list.  If not, then it may be simplest to get it; failing that, `for file in *.txt; do sed '/^IAM A DEFAULT/d' "$file" > x && mv x "$file"; done`, assuming a POSIX-ish shell (and no valuable local file called `x` since it gets zapped).

Comment: @krthk: Please don't use abbreviated user names when you're replying: it bypasses Stack Overflow's notification system. If you're using a PC system then you can hit the `@` sign and start typing the name of the user you're replying to; hitting tab will autocomplete. Adding a username to a comment properly like that will alert them as an increment in their inbox. Please try it. Sadly this doesn't work on the tablet and phone apps, and you're stuffed if you want to reply to someone with Unicode characters in the username unless you have a fancy keyboard

Comment: @krthk: Your question doesn't give any detail. No one has even mentioned where these text files are or how we are to find them. But what you haven't answered yet is which lines are to be deleted, hence Perl Dog's frustration in capital letters I also understand that you think you've explained several times over with words like *"It is a single line with same string in all files"*. The problem is that that's not precise enough!

Comment: @krthk:  You talk about the string `IAM A DEFAULT` being *present in the string*, but does that include lines like `xyzzxIAM A DEFAULTPhenome`? Should a line that begins with tabs or space characters, or anything else funny, before `IAM A DEFAULT` be included? The same applies to the rest of the string. If I find a line `IAM A DEFAULT` followed by a space then do you want that removed? I have guessed a lot to write my answer below, based on what people *usually want* when they say things like what you've said. But I'm far from certain that it's correct. Please indulge us in the future!

Comment: @Borodin Please don't be so harsh. This is a beginner, he doesn't know better and the Q wasn't that bad. After some interrogation he told which lines to skip. I think he doesn't care/know exactly whether the lines have add'l whitespace or not.

Comment: @PerlDog: I honestly thought I was being accommodating. I was trying to explain why what the OP probably thought was definitive was actually less than sufficient for the purposes of coding a solution. If I had thought the OP was reasonably seasoned programmer then I wouldn't have explained the difference between *contains* and *equals*. I also thought a smattering of exclamation marks would help. I'll leave my words in place in the hope that someone else finds them useful, but thank you for telling me how things seem to you

Comment: @Borodin I don't want to argue. It's always an honor when you comment on a Q and your answers are always very profound. Tell me what you want, but you are one of the Godfathers of Perl here on SO. (@krthk: Read that?). My conclusion is: Peace? Peace!

Comment: @PerlDog: I'm not arguing; just sad to hear that my words were seen as harsh. Thank you for your compliments--I shall continue to do my best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed and GNU bash 4:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
sed -i '/^IAM A DEFAULT/d' **/*.txt
```

Comment: Hi Cyrus, it worked thanks. but how  i do the same for all txt files in sub folders?

Answer (score 3):

You don't talk about identifying the files to be processed, but let's assume that you want to remove all `IAM A DEFAULT` lines from all `*.txt` files in the current directory

This Perl one-line command will doe that for you. It will also save each original file like `abc.txt` as `abc.txt.bak`

```
perl -i.bak -lne 'print unless $_ eq "IAM A DEFAULT"' *.txt
```

I hope that helps